# How to generate Application Signed Request for sinch user call report API

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I want to get user call report from sinch, for that i need to generate application signed request.

https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#UserCallReport

I can not find demo to generate application signed request for android in documentation.

I am getting this error message when fire request in postman

**Request:**
    GET https://reportingapi.sinch.com/v1/users/username/jigar1/calls/

```
Params -> Authorization : Application 554042e3-965c-4e88-a7b8-3f2b52c278f3:t0fsMPGjaNiAEjT+29FyHnHuzaKDAOT3rShXWQp3IcA=
          X-Timestamp : 2016-06-21T06:37:43Z
```

**Response :**

```
{
  "errorCode": 40102,
  "message": "Invalid Signature.",
  "reference": "A:554042e3-965c-4e88-a7b8-3f2b52c278f3_JEC6uQxEUkSkNmSkvvNwXA"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pseudo code here
https://www.sinch.com/using-rest/#applicationsignedrequest

Or you can use basic auth

Comment: I have used same URL reference to create authorization header but its gives same error "Invalid Signature"

Comment: Please answer this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39997169/sinch-phonenumberutils-issue-for-indonesia-number

Comment: CAn you share the code in teh question so i can have a look?

Comment: can you please look in to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677108/sinch-get-an-event-for-no-internet-connection-while-on-going-voice-call

Answer (score 0):

I have used some reports from Sinch. To authenticate my requests I'm using the demo in the [Sinch Github account](https://github.com/sinch/), you can check the [repo here](https://github.com/sinch/php-auth-ticket). This will work fine for you.

With the request https://reportingapi.sinch.com/v1/users/username/1234571/calls/ I got the response

```
{
"start": "2017-10-31T00:00:00",
"duration": 0,
"success": 0,
"failed": 0
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to do the same and posted the code at:

[User Call Report API gives incorrect results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883189/user-call-report-api-gives-incorrect-results)

Which is based on:

https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/sign-requests-java

I have a different problem with that code, but at least it does not
give any "Invalid Signature" message.