# Sinch : Get an event for no internet connection while on going voice call

Tags: android, sinch

I am working on voice call application using sinch sdk.

Calling functionality works perfect!

but, I didn't get any event on caller side if callee's internet connection disconnect while ongoing voice call.

I found following log in logcat when other end internet connection disconnect. but unable locate it as they are from sinch SDK

```
W/sinch-android-rtc: webrtc: (rtp_rtcp_impl.cc:167): Process: Timeout: No RTCP RR received.
W/sinch-android-rtc: webrtc: (rtp_rtcp_impl.cc:169): Process: Timeout: No increase in RTCP RR extended highest sequence number.
```

Comment: Have you resolved it yet? I guess I can help you with.

Comment: @SamH67 please submit your answer, it may help everyone looking for solution of this problem. This is a community site, here we try to help every single person and not just focus on a single guy.

Answer (score 0):

Thats by design, incase the callee gets connected again. Since its udp packets we just send them any way really no way of knowing if they arrive.

We could of course look if we recieve anything but we thought it was better to see if it connected again.